# On the combination between "to be allowed to" and "to be entitled to"

Tags: verb-agreement

We have:

> I am allowed **to do** something.

and

> I am entitled **to doing** something.

When we combine the two of them, do we have:

> I am both [**allowed**] and [entitled] [**to do**] something.

or

> I am both [allowed] and [**entitled**] [**to doing**] something.

Comment: 'To do' is more natural.

Answer (score 3):

Only the version with the infinitive, *BE allowed and entitled to VERB*, is acceptable. In this construction the subject of *BE allowed* and *BE entitled* is also the subject of *to VERB*. The *to* here is an infinitive marker.

*Entitled to do**ing*** is not idiomatic. An *-ing* form would be acceptable as object of *to* (which in this context is a preposition) only if it had the very ‘nouny’ sense of some benefit which can be received by the subject of *be entitled*, not when it represents an action whose subject is the same as the subject of *be entitled*. For instance:

> Beggars at the kitchen are entitled to leavings of the banquet.

Here *leavings* has the sense "that which is left" when the banquet is concluded; it is not the beggars who *leave* these remnants but the diners.

Answer (score -2):

Being *allowed* to do something means that you have been given permission to do it but the permission is not automatic and could be revoked or refused on another occasion. 
Being *entitled* to do something means that you have a right to do it, no permission is needed, and the entitlement would have to be removed, probably legally, before you could be prevented from doing it.
For example you may be *allowed* to sit in your neighbour's garden because she likes you, but if you fall out she can remove the permission. However you are *entitled* to sit in your own garden because you either own it or have a lease on it.

Comment: Check whether the OP is asking about the difference between allowed and entitled, or really 'to do' or 'to doing.'

Comment: Yosef is correct. FYI This answer has made it on the Low Quality Posts review queue.